# javascript floating decimal

Tags: javascript, math, floating-point, decimal

I have a bit of javascript that dynamically multiplies what users are typing in a text field (by the base var), and displays it in a span. Now I'm just trying to figure out how to get the decimal places of the result to float to 2 places, i.e. 10.00 instead of 10
I found the toFixed function, but can't seem to use it properly... I'd appreciate any help. Thanks

```
<input id="quantity">
<span id="result"></span> 
<script>

window.onload = function() {
   var base = 3;
   document.getElementById('quantity').onkeyup = function() {
      if(this.value.length == 0) {
         document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '';
         return;
      }
      var number = parseInt(this.value);
      if(isNaN(number)) return;
      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = number * base;
   };
   document.getElementById('quantity').onkeyup();
};
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `parseInt` here? It will turn '4.21' into '4'. So the user will be told that 4.21 * 3 = 12.00, which it doesn't. `parseFloat` will yield a floating point value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.onload = function() { 
 var base = 3; 
 document.getElementById('quantity').onkeyup = function() { 
   if(this.value.length == 0) { 
     document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = ''; 
     return; 
   }    
   if(isNaN(this.value)) 
     return; 
   var number = parseFloat(this.value); 
   var result = (number * base).toFixed(2);
   document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result; 
   }; 
   document.getElementById('quantity').onkeyup();
};
```

Comment: Firstly, can you change `parseInt` to `parseFloat`, since the asker is unlikely to want an integer multiplied to 2dp. Also, it might be clearer to have either `var result = (number * base).toFixed(2);` (expressing it in one statement), or to have two variables and have `var preciseResult = number * base; var result = preciseResult.toFixed(2);`.